# Interpretation of Open Group Base Specification's description of exit()

Tags: linux, exit

In the `exit()` function description of the Open Group Base Specifications (various issues), we read:

> The `exit()` function shall first call all functions registered by
> atexit(), in the reverse order of their registration, **except that a
> function is called after any previously registered functions that had
> already been called at the time it was registered**.

It is my fault for sure, but I cannot understand (and recognize the syntax structure!) of the statement in boldface.
May I ask for somebody to rephrase and explain what is the meaning of this statement? Possibly with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That part of the specification deals with functions which are registered from another exit handler. Consider

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(void) {
  puts("func1");
}

void func2(void) {
  puts("func2");
}

void func4(void);

void func3(void) {
  atexit(func4);
  puts("func3");
}

void func4(void) {
  puts("func4");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  atexit(func1);
  atexit(func2);
  atexit(func3);
}
```

The functions are registered in numeric order: `func1`, `func2`, `func3` from `main`, and `func4` from `func3` (which is the first handler invoked, being the last registered handler when `main` exits). Because `func3` has already been called when `func4` is registered, it is no longer considered in the execution order of handlers:

```sh
$ make exit
cc exit.c -o exit
$ ./exit
func3
func4
func2
func1
```

Without the part you highlighted, a strict interpretation would suggest that `func4` should be called before `func3` (which is impossible), or that `func3` should be called (again) after `func4`, or that handlers can no longer be registered once exit handling has started (to preserve the execution order).

Comment: (darn, I fiddled too long with the code...) I actually read the leading part as requiring the impossible, i.e. not that `func3()` should be called again after `func4()`, but that it shouldn't have been called before it in the first place. That's what the reverse registration order would imply.

Comment: Right, I read that as a possible interpretation too, but if `func3` isn’t called before `func4`, `func4` is never registered, which is a bit of a catch-22 ;-).

Answer (score 2):

1. After a program calls `exit(3)` (or returns from the `main()` function), all the functions *already* registered with `atexit(3)` will be called in the reverse order of their registration.
2. But a function registered with `atexit(3)` (let's call it `foo()`) can itself call `atexit(3)` and register *another function* (`bar()`), which will be pushed to the *front* of the list, and will be called just after `foo()`.

So `bar()` will be called after `foo()`, despite being registered *after* `foo()`, which is an exception to the "rule" that "all functions are called in the reverse order of their registration".

Hope this helps.